# Error in configuring iOS App for Push Notifications with Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, push-notification, ios-provisioning

I am following [all the instructions here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYr-tMCD454) (i'm using Swift) without error. I can even build the project fine. When I connect my iPhone (5C) and try to run the app on the phone, I get the following error

Here's the error message in case it is not visible in the image:

`Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 1`

What am I doing wrong? I am using iPhone 5C for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hate to answer my own question but this issue is resolved now. I restarted the project completely and followed all the steps again, no issue anymore.